# Java sort by 2 parameter from CSV file

Tags: java, sorting, csv

current output: [http://imgur.com/r93GReF](https://imgur.com/r93GReF)
 sorted by highest mark only.

How do i make it such that it would sort by highest mark first followed by lowest attempt? Example xxxxx,6,1,xxxx,6,1 xxxx,6,4, .....

Help!!!!!! stuck for hours!

```
public static void sort() {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.csv"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Map < String, List < String >> map = new TreeMap < String, List < String >> ();
    String line;
    try {
        line = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //read header
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String key = getField(line);

            List < String > l = map.get(key);

            if (l == null) {
                l = new LinkedList < String > ();
                map.put(key, l);
            }
            l.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("HALL OF FAME\nMatric, Marks, Attempt");
    map = ((TreeMap < String, List < String >> ) map).descendingMap();

    for (List < String > list: map.values()) {
        for (String val: list) {
            System.out.println(val);
        }
    }
}


private static String getField(String line) {
    return line.split(",")[1]; // extract value you want to sort on
}
```

Comment: Why the screenshot? Just paste your output into the question.

Comment: Don't post links to data that should be included within your post. How do you expect your question to assist others once your provided link goes dead (and it will definitely go dead)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to work!

```
public static void sort() throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.csv"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    Map<MarkAndAttempt, List<String>> map =
            new TreeMap<MarkAndAttempt, List<String>>(new Comparator<MarkAndAttempt>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(MarkAndAttempt o1, MarkAndAttempt o2) {
                    if (o1.getMark() > o2.getMark()) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (o1.getMark() == o2.getMark()) {
                        return o1.getAttempt() > o2.getAttempt() ? 1 : -1;
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            });
    String line;
    try {
        reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//read header
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //String key = getField(line);

            //List<String> l = map.get(key);

            MarkAndAttempt markAndAttempt = generateMarkAndAttempt(line);
            List<String> l = map.get(markAndAttempt);

            if (l == null) {
                l = new LinkedList<String>();
                map.put(markAndAttempt, l);
            }
            l.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("HALL OF FAME\nMatric, Marks, Attempt");

    for (List<String> list : map.values()) {
        for (String val : list) {
            System.out.println(val);
        }



    }
}


private static MarkAndAttempt generateMarkAndAttempt(String line) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(line);
    String[] parts = line.split(",");
    if (parts.length != 3) throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    return new MarkAndAttempt(Integer.valueOf(parts[1].trim()), Integer.valueOf(parts[2].trim()));
}

private static String getField(String line) {
    return line.split(",")[1];// extract value you want to sort on
}

static class MarkAndAttempt {

    private int mark;

    private int attempt;

    public MarkAndAttempt(int mark, int attempt) {
        this.mark = mark;
        this.attempt = attempt;
    }

    public int getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(int mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    public int getAttempt() {
        return attempt;
    }

    public void setAttempt(int attempt) {
        this.attempt = attempt;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        MarkAndAttempt that = (MarkAndAttempt) o;

        return mark == that.mark;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return mark;
    }
}
```

Comment: multiple marker at this line.  comparator cannot be resolved into a type. the constructor tree map .... is undefined.

Comment: the method compare (main... ) must override or implement a super method.. googling

Comment: import comparator*. doing now

Comment: the source csv file format doesnot like the underline:  `A,2,2
B,3,1
C,2,1
A,2,3
B,1,0
D,2,2`

Comment: Result is still the same :( .  - i imported constructor and object. What could be wrong? since yours works

Comment: xxxx [6,1] , kkkkkk [6,1] , vvvv [6,4] .......  should be arranged first

Comment: can you export your project and upload for me to see whats the difference?

Comment: nice! Thank you Saber! MUCH APPRECIATED

Comment: BTW, the tree map value List<String> can modify to just String `Map<MarkAndAttempt, String> map = ... `